# How do generate and fill a datasource by code?

Tags: vb.net, datasource

i have created a combobox.datasource by code

```
salmon.DataSource = {New With {.Text = CDate("1.4.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "1"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.5.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "2"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.6.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "3"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.7.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "4"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.8.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "5"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.9.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "6"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.10.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "7"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.11.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "8"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.12.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "9"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.1.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "10"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.2.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "11"},
                     New With {.Text = CDate("1.3.20").ToString("MMM"), Key .Value = "12"}}
```

how can I fill this datasource by programming a loop like
for i=1 to 12
 ???
next

Comment: Looks like Value would be your variable "i", and your date would be with a DateTime.AddDays function.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a datatable, with custom column names and types, fill it with data, and assign it to show in the combo. :

```
Dim dt as New Datatable
dt.Columns.Add("DisplayCol")
dt.Columns.Add("ValueCol", GetType(Integer))

Dim d as New DateTime(1999, 12, 1)
For int i = 1 to 12
  dt.Rows.Add(d.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMM"), i)
Next i

combo.DataSource = dt
combo.DisplayMember = "DisplayCol" 'tell the combo what column name to use for display text
combo.ValueMember = "ValueCol" 'tell the combo what column to use for value
```

I made the value col an int deliberately to demonstrate how it could be done. If you want a string, remove the GetType in the constructor of the column and also call i.ToString()

The combo will actually bind to the DefaultView of the table, so we can use this to sort and filter what shows in the combo:

```
'if dt is still in scope
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "[ValueCol] DESC"

'if we only can access the datatable via the datasource property of the combo
DirectCast(combo.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.Sort = "[ValueCol] DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @LarsTech suppose you may need something like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 12
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(CDate("1." & i.ToString & "." & Now.Year.ToString).ToString("MMM"), i.ToString))
Next

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
AddHandler ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged, Sub()
                                               MsgBox("Key:" & CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key & vbNewLine &
                                                      "Value:" & CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value)
                                           End Sub
```